# GWT: Mark of the web (MOTW)

Tags: gwt

"Mark of the Web" headers are HTML comments that tell Internet Explorer it might be okay to run Javascript.  They look something like this:

```
 <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Anyone know a simple way to configure a GWT project to automatically build these into all files during development?  Any other changes required to get GWT sites to actually launch happily from local disk without overriding the security warnings?

Comment: Why do you need that? It's the first time I heard of such a requirement.

Comment: Well, "need" is probably too strong, but I want to do so because the IE security model blocks execution of Javascript stored locally.  It would be helpful for testing to be able to run the real code (not the Java emulation) with the real security settings (not just overriding the warnings) without moving the code to a separate server, which would work, or manually scattering MOTW headers throughout the HTML.

Comment: Why not just run a server on your pc and point the server to put your build directory online? Or just write a script to FTP or SCP the compiled JS to the server?